# InnerHTML erase the value while adding muliple text boxes

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am following [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4397238/how-to-create-textbox-dynamically-in-php)

to add dynamic text boxes. But my issue is, when I insert the values in the second text box, and then press the button for next text box the values in the second box is erased. So I can't use the submit form. Is there any way to fix it?

HTML

```
<table style="width:500px;height:auto;">
<tr>
<th>Code-1</th>
<td><input type="text" name="code1" id="code"></td><td><input type="button" value="Add New Code" onClick="insert()"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Custom Markup-1</th><td>
<input type="text" name="markup1" id="markup"></td></tr>
<tr><th>Vendor-1</th><td>
<select id="v" name="v1">
<option value="0">Please Select..</option>
<?
while($v= mysql_fetch_array($vendor))
{
    echo "<option value=".$v['id'].">".$v['name']."</option>";
}
?>
</select></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

JS

```
<script language="javascript">
var i = 1;
function insert()
{
new_div.innerHTML = new_div.innerHTML +"<tr><th>Code-"+(i+1)+"</th><td><input type='text' id='code"+(i+1)+"' name='code"+(i+1)+"'></td></tr>";
new_div.innerHTML = new_div.innerHTML +"<tr><th>Custom Markup-"+(i+1)+"</th><td><input type='text' name='markup"+(i+1)+"'/></td></tr>";
new_div.innerHTML = new_div.innerHTML +"<tr><th>Vendor-"+(i+1)+"</th><td><select id='v'+i name='v"+(i+1)+"'><option value='0'>Please Select..</option><?php while($v= mysql_fetch_array($vendorInfo)){?><option value='<?php echo $v['id']; ?>'><?php echo $v['name']; ?></option><?php }?></select></td></tr>";
new_div.innerHTML = new_div.innerHTML +"<tr><td><hr></td><td><hr></td></tr>";
//document.getElementById('code2').value=document.getElementById('code2').value;
i++;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Post your code. Are you assigning innerHTML or concatenating it?

Comment: It's the same code as the answer of above link. I am assigning innerhtml, not concatenating. So I think when i press the button innerhtml will be refresh

Comment: Still, it's easier to see the code here than to follow a link. If you're assigning the innerHTML, it replaces everything already there. Use innerHTML += [dynamic stuff]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this on :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script>
            var txtBId=1;
            function addTB(){
                var div=document.getElementById("tbSet");
                var txt=document.createElement("input");
                txt.setAttribute("type","text");
                txt.setAttribute("id","tb"+(txtBId++));  
                // div.innerHTML=div.innerHTML +"<br>";    <------------------  
                var br=document.createElement("br");
                div.appendChild(br);         
                div.appendChild(txt);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="myform">

            <div id="tbSet">

            </div>
            <input type="button" value="New TextBox" onclick="addTB();">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">

        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I still have problem with code as well. If I added three or more text boxes, the data will be erased from all text boxes before submit

Comment: yes, the above code is working. But I was wondering how can I add the dynamic drop down menu from my code?

Answer (score 0):

Donot add text box by innerHtml,. If you add it , after 3 data will be erased . Do it bu createElement, and then addpend the child.

```
 function addTB(){
                var div=document.getElementById("tbSet");
                var txt=document.createElement("input");
                txt.setAttribute("type","text");
                txt.setAttribute("id","tb"+(txtBId++));                
                var br=document.createElement("br");
                div.appendChild(br);         
                div.appendChild(txt);
     }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not familiar with createElement. Let me try it. Can we create table, dyanamic drop boxes using this createElement?

Comment: createElement can be used for any Html tag.

Answer (score 0):

For Drop down :

```
var slId=1;
            function options(name,value){

                 var o=document.createElement("option");
                 o.setAttribute("value",value);
                 o.innerHTML=name;
                 return o;

            }
            function addDropDown(){
                  var div=document.getElementById("tbSet");
                var sl=document.createElement("select");                 
                 var o=options("Hello","hi");            
                 sl.setAttribute("id","sl"+(slId++));
                 sl.appendChild(o);                 
                 div.appendChild(sl);
            }
```

Comment: if you don't mind, please show me how to do with that while loop? I am searching for it. But didn't get the exact answer!

Comment: Hi, php runs on server side. So store the vedor information in some javascript array. And use thar array , in a while loop format .